# Using Administrate gem, how to render edit page via custom update action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, thoughtbot, administrate

I'm trying to have my custom update action for my user controller render the edit page if they fail to validate, like so:

```
def update
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.update(user_params)
  # zero because checkbox
  user_params[:banned] == "0" ? user.remove_role(:banned) : user.add_role(:banned)
  if user.banned_note
    if user.banned_note.update(content: params[:user][:reason_for_ban])
      redirect_to "/admin/users/#{params[:id]}"
    else
      render "edit.html.erb"                                    # this line
    end
  end
end

def find_resource(param)
  User.find!(id: param)
end
```

I want to render the edit page with a flash message listing the errors, but what I have doesn't work. I'm not sure how to route to the correct action, since there's no actual view or edit action (which are auto generated by the Administrate gem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandy, I have not used this gem but looking the [source code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/blob/master/app/controllers/administrate/application_controller.rb#L35) and this [comment](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/issues/195#issuecomment-176279517) of this [issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/issues/195) in GitHub, Have you try the following?

```
def update
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.update(user_params)
  # zero because checkbox
  user_params[:banned] == "0" ? user.remove_role(:banned) : user.add_role(:banned)
  if user.banned_note
    if user.banned_note.update(content: params[:user][:reason_for_ban])
      redirect_to "/admin/users/#{params[:id]}"
    else
      #This two lines
      flash.now[:notice] = "Something"
      render :new, locals: {
        page: Administrate::Page::Form.new(dashboard, resource),
      }
    end
  end
end

def find_resource(param)
  User.find!(id: param)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Matayoshi. I did try something similar to that, but I get `undefined method or variable: resource` when that happens. I think that's on the right track but I'm not sure how to manipulate it so I could use it.

Comment: Try `user` instead of `resource`

Comment: Works!!! Thanks so much! How did you get to that answer? I was looking at that action in their docs:
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/administrate/Administrate/ApplicationController#edit-instance_method

But I didn't know to replace `requested_resource` with `user`.

Comment: Sorry if it's a loaded or stupid question. I just want to know your thinking process. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @PandyZhao it OK, it is a good question! You were close, the only thing is that you do not defined the `resource` variable, you defined as `user`. The resource is in this case is the User, because it is the UsersController